# Is it possible to run a 64-bit program WITHOUT creating a Virtual Machine with an OS?

Tags: windows-7, virtual-machine, 64-bit, 32-bit

I want to install Premiere Pro CC, but since I have a 32-bit laptop, I can't, so the only solution is a virtual machine.

Before I start these are my PC's specs (not great but they do the job):

- Intel Core 2 Duo P8400 @2.27Ghz (capable of virtualization if you are wondering)
- 3GB of DDR2 RAM
- NVIDIA GeForce 9600M GT 512MB
- Windows 7 Ultimate Service Pack 1 32-bit

I wanted to try a simple virtual machine before I get Windows and whatnot, so I tried Ubuntu 18.04, downloaded it, set it up in Oracle VirtualBox and configured it. I gave the virtual machine as much RAM as I could (2GB almost), but of course it wasn't enough, Ubuntu was lagging like crazy moving a window was so painfully slow, so I gave up on that idea, but I still want to use Premiere Pro CC.

There is actually a version of Premiere Pro that can run 32-bit, but that was CS4 and so from 2009, which was lacking a lot of features I needed.

So, I'm asking if there is a way so that I can use Premiere Pro CC, maybe an emulator, maybe something else?

If there isn't any solution, can someone tell me if i can run Windows 10 64-bit without any problems or lag?

And if I can run Windows 10 64-bit, can I run Premiere Pro CC 2014?

Comment: definitely it can run 64-bit Windows without problem. However its specs is far from being running video editors smoothly. Running hard work like that inside a VM is even worse, let alone an *emulator*

Comment: The Windows 10 update tool (https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10) should tell you whether your machine is capable of running the latest version of the OS. If you want to install 64-bit though you will have to do a clean install and not an upgrade.

Comment: Ok i'll make a clean install of windows 10 64-bit but is it possible for me to install it on my external hard drive?

Comment: @watass You just keep making worse... Honestly, running Win 10 64-bit in a VM on an external drive with this hardware won't be smooth or lag-free, it will be anywhere from annoyingly to frustratingly slow, especially in very processor heavy applications like video editors. You might want to just accept your hardware is not sufficient for the task.

Comment: I meant to install Windows 10 64-bit as a host os, not in a vm @acejavelin

Comment: Running it on the external drive adds the drive interface as a bottleneck - assuming you could even install it. I know windows2go would work, and can be installed off rufus

Comment: i'll see what i can do about the external hdd, but can i run Premiere Pro CC 2014? or the old CC (the one just after CS6)??

Comment: If you want to reformat your laptop, you can install Win 10 64-bit as the host OS, but that won't change anything in reality. You need to accept the fact that fact that video editing software is beyond the capabilities of your hardware. Even Premier Pro CC 2014 requires a MINIMUM of 4GB of RAM and it cannot be installed on removable storage. For what you want to do you need to accept the fact that your hardware is not sufficient.

Comment: @acejavelin that's not helpful, but it's realistic, i'm gonna try it tomorrow and tell you if I succeeded, if not i'm gonna have to keep using Premiere Pro CS4 then

Comment: Helpful or not, it is a valid comment of fact and not opinion, I will not sugar coat it to make you think it might work. Also, Premiere Pro CS4 should be fine, even CS5/5.5 should be OK, but as of CS6 through CC 2014 the requirement is a minimum of 4GB of RAM with 8GB recommended, and after that 8GB is the bare minimum.

Comment: it's possible to install a program with less RAM than officially required, but then running it would be a problem. You won't be able to use advanced features of it and will also quickly run out of VRAM, as most modern non-linear video editors make use of GPUs to accelerate the rendering and edting process

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your primary question is:

> Is it possible to run a 64-bit program WITHOUT creating a Virtual
>   Machine with an OS?

That answer, for what you are looking for is no... You cannot run a Windows program such as Premiere Pro in a VM without a valid operating system. Most programs for specific operating systems have significant dependencies on the core OS and other libraries that are part of that operating system, you can't just "run" a program like that in a VM environment with no operating system. It would be like trying to put that applications DVD in the optical drive and boot and run it that way on a blank PC, it just isn't possible.

Your next question was:

> If there isn't any solution, can someone tell me if i can run Windows
>   10 64-bit without any problems or lag?

That one is much more difficult to answer, but given the capabilities of your host machine, meaning that you would install Windows 10 64-bit in a VirtualBox VM with 2GB of RAM allocated to it, which is completely possible to do... But the question was specifically "without any problems or lag" which is much more difficult to answer, but I will address Adobe Premier Pro only as that is what you stated as your primary software requirement but this will still require some speculation. Running even Premier Pro CS4 will be very slow and laggy in this environment, and running anything newer would fail as there isn't sufficient RAM to run the application.

The alternative would be install Windows 10 64-bit directly on the hardware as the primary OS, which would be better but given the hardware that is involved I doubt it would make things much better and the fact it only has 3GB of RAM will not allow a version of Premier Pro newer than CS5.5 to work. Premier Pro of any version is very hardware intensive, it's [minimum specifications](https://helpx.adobe.com/premiere-pro/system-requirements.html) are fairly robust for it's release dates, including recommendations of 7200rpm hard drives with RAID0 recommended.

And the last question:

> And if I can run Windows 10 64-bit, can I run Premiere Pro CC 2014?

Assuming you mean as the primary hardware OS, and not in a VM, the answer is no. You stated your hardware was:

- Intel Core 2 Duo P8400 @2.27Ghz
- 3GB of DDR2 RAM
- NVIDIA GeForce 9600M GT 512MB

But a minimum requirements for Premiere Pro CC is 4GB of RAM, which your system does not have. The installer may allow you to install it, but there is a reason Adobe set those requirements, so something will not work properly it works at all. Premiere Pro CC 2014 has even more robust hardware requirements so that version if out of the question.

Comment: Disappointing answer for me, but it's true, so the lesson is: buy a new pc. I want to buy a new PC of course, but right now I just can't, so I'll have to keep using Premiere Pro CS4.

Comment: @watass It might not have to be a "new" PC... Just one good enough to do the job you need it to do. I don't know about where you live, but here we can go to a state surplus office and get a quad core box with 4-8GB of RAM for about $50. I know this varies a LOT by location around the world, but your PC is probably 10 years old (P8400 was introduced in June 2008), and most businesses replace on a 4-6 year cycle, so it shouldn't be too hard to find something new enough to do what you need with minimal investment if you do a little digging.

Comment: In my country computers are more expensive than they should, and there is barely any actual PCs in my local store (Virgin Megastore) that are actually worth buying other than that single Alienware laptop, any thing else is just Macbooks, or iMacs, and I just don't like getting a Mac.

And if you're thinking about me building a PC, almost nobody here sells parts, so I have to order them, which can take weeks or months in my case.

Answer (score 1):

Treating this question as an XY problem... You want to run a good video editor. Your choice is Adobe Premiere Pro CC 2014. It's quite clear that your PC cannot handle this properly, even if you can get it installed in a VM. I've run Photoshop CS4 on an old Ubuntu desktop (2003 Dell) with an Windows XP VM. That worked pretty well, although sometimes slow. Premiere 2014 is something else, because it's video.

How about [Lightworks](https://www.lwks.com/)? Maybe you need an older version. Maybe it runs faster on Linux so you might need a dual install Windows/Ubuntu on your machine. I've used it, and in the beginning it's a pain to get to understand the user interface. But I bet it can do most of what you need, unless you need some specific Premiere filters or effects. Maybe it's no option if you have existing projects, but still it's better than not running anything.

It's free (as in beer) if you register, export to 720p video is free, and if you need more, you take a one month subscription for $20 when the project is ready, just for the export.

Comment: Don't worry about it anymore, I just installed Windows 10 64-bit as a host OS, and I installed Premiere Pro CC 2018, and it runs really good....I'm serious, I can edit 720p video footage, so if i have to edit 1080p or maybe 4K footage, I still have the choice to make proxys so yeah problem solved.

Answer (score -1):

I tried installing a Windows 10 64-bit host OS anyways because Adobe Premiere Pro CS4 was lacking too many features I need, so I installed Windows 10 64-bit on my PC, installed Premiere Pro CC 2015.3 (I couldn't dare try the latest version, because that would be a waste of time).

Guess what? It worked! For the kind of footage I was working with (which is 720p footage that are later encoded into 1080p) it worked! As long as I don't have any other program open, Premiere Pro works smoothly.

Have in mind, I still want a new PC, but for now I'm going to stick with this.

PS: I tried working with a whole hour of footage and it worked well.

And one last thing, I wasn't able to edit 1080p footage when i was using CS4, but now with CC 2015, it works pretty smoothly. Might have been a software issue.

Update: Installed CC 2018, It worked well too.

> Thank you for reading this answer. **But you shouldn't use Premiere Pro
>   on a low-end PC even thought it worked for me.**

Comment: The issue is that acejavelin already suggested installing Windows 10 64-bit directly on your hardware as the primary OS.  While we’re glad that it worked for you, we generally discourage people from posting answers that principally report that another answer worked.  You should accept acejavelin’s answer, and maybe add your cautions and caveats as a comment.